# update json element in json object using python

Tags: python, json

Here is my json object in python

```
json1 = {
  "success":true,
  "message":"",
  "result":[{
    "MarketName":"USDT-BTC"
}]}

json2 = {
"success1":true1
}
```

I want to update results element in json1 object using json2 in python

```
json1 = {
  "success":true,
  "message":"",
  "result":{
"success1":true1
}}
```

can you please let me know how to do it

Comment: Terminology nitpick: there is no json in this question. json1 and json2 are perfectly ordinary dictionaries. This may help you in your research. For example, searching for "merge dictionaries" may give you better results than "merge jsons"

Comment: What are `true` and `true1`?

Comment: Kevin's comment is actually not a "terminology nitpick" but the sensible thing to mention: what you're dealing with are just plain Python dicts. There's actually no such thing as "a json object" in Python.

Comment: Just replace the result key value with the new value. It is not a json

Answer (score 2):

If the type of *json1* and *json2* are dict you can use

```
json1['result'] = json2
```

but if they are strings at first you must use **json.loads** for *json1* and *json2* and use mentioned code for updating the value.

```
import json
json.loads(json1)
json.loads(json2)
json1['result'] = json2
```

Answer (score 1):

The easey way is reassign your new dict into existing key.

```
>>> json1 = { "success": True, "message":"", "result":[{ "MarketName":"USDT-BTC" }]}
>>> json2 = { "success1":True }
>>> json1['result'] = json2
>>> json1
{'success': True, 'message': '', 'result': {'success1': True}}
```

You may access into a key using `dict["key"]` and assign a new value `dict["key"] = new_value`.

Depends on you want to do, you should  iterate over an array (whether if you had) changing this value or any action you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use update function: json1.update(json2)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json` library for serializing and deserializing JSON data.

```
In [1]: import json

In [2]: json1 = '{ "success": true, "message":"", "result":[{ "MarketName":"USDT-BTC" }]}'

In [3]: json2 = '{ "success1":true }'

In [4]: dict1 = json.loads(json1) # Deserialize a str or unicode instance containing a JSON document to a Python object

In [5]: dict2 = json.loads(json2)

In [6]: dict1
Out[6]: {u'message': u'', u'result': [{u'MarketName': u'USDT-BTC'}], u'success': True}

In [7]: dict2
Out[7]: {u'success1': True}

In [8]: dict1['result'] = dict2

In [9]: dict1
Out[9]: {u'message': u'', u'result': {u'success1': True}, u'success': True}

In [10]: final_json = json.dumps(dict1) # Serialize obj to a JSON formatted str

In [11]: final_json
Out[11]: '{"message": "", "result": {"success1": true}, "success": true}'
```